# How can I share my iMac's internet connection with my iPad?

Tags: ipad, wifi, network, imac

i have an iMac, that has internet access via cable (no WiFi).

I know, that my iMac has Wi-Fi access point.

How can I share the internet connection of iMac with iPad?

Answer (score 7):

The answer you're looking for, though, is Internet Sharing:

1. Go into the System Preferences on your iMac
2. Go to Sharing, then click on Internet Sharing
3. In the dropdown, indicate that you want to "Share your connection from" Ethernet
4. Check the Airport box
5. You have the option to set your network name, channel, and to use WEP encryption by clicking "Airport Options".
6. Finally, check the box next to "Internet Sharing" on the left hand side.
7. At the prompt, click Start.

You should now be able to connect to the internet on your iPad by selecting the network you set up on your iMac.

USB sharing is also now easy and fast: [Can I share my iMac's internet to iPhone or iPad over USB?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb)

Comment: Please do not use WEP. Please! Do! Not! Use! WEP!

Comment: @wjlafrance the only alternative is to use no encryption at all

Comment: Sorry, I could have sworn WPA was in that list. Looks like I've got a bug report to file. Thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: @wjl Is your first comment incorrect ?

Comment: @Simon When this answer was written, the only options were WEP or no security. Now the options are WPA2 or no security.

Comment: I thought this had changed at some point but couldn't remember when. Thanks @KyleCronin for verifying. To clarify my first comment, WEP is very insecure (broken within seconds) and for anyone actually interested in breaking in, is equivalent to having no encryption at all.

Comment: @KyleCronin Thanks for clarifying, just so I understand it WPA2 is the preference nowadays.

Comment: @wjl Thanks for your response, I think I understand now based on Kyle's response

Answer (score 0):

You can also share connectivity with iOS by USB cable (if you can not use WiFi), but it is little hacky: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232937/98580