# How can I share iMac Internet connection (using SOCKS) with iPad via Bluetooth?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, bluetooth, proxy

On my iMac I access the Internet with a SOCKS proxy. This is created with SSH like so:

```
ssh -D 5492 user@server
```

I then set the SOCKS proxy settings in `System Settings > Network > Wi-Fi -> Proxies`. It works fine and I can browse the web via my SOCKS proxy.

I want to share the Internet with my iPad via bluetooth. I have the iPad connected to the iMac via bluetooth and the Internet sharing is set up on the iMac.

The problem is the iPad is connecting via my ISP and not via the SOCKS proxy. I have Wi-Fi disabled on the iPad so I know for sure it's not connecting via the router.

Is there any way to have the iPad go via the SOCKS proxy?

Comment: Would usb sharing work? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb

Comment: I can confirm that USB sharing doesn't go through the SOCKS proxy.  OSX 10.15.7 and iOS 14.6 on an iPhone 6S+.