# Internet Sharing to iPhone over USB not working

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, network, usb

I'm unable to [share my macOS Ethernet connection with my iPhone over USB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100363/5472). I tried both the 'Internet Sharing' and the 'Content Caching' methods. I can see the iPhone in Finder but the iPhone does not connect to the internet. I can also see and select 'iPhone USB' inside 'Internet Sharing' when the iPhone is connected.

macOS: 10.15.7 - iOS: 14.1

I'm testing in an iMac 2020 with a built-in Ethernet adapter and the iPhone is directly connected to a USB port on the Mac. There is only one Ethernet port in System Preferences > Network

Should it suppose to appear as Ethernet on the iPhone?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [this tutorial](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-share-mac-wifi-with-iphone-ipad/).  It will share your ethernet over Bluetooth instead of USB.

Comment: Bluetooth sharing does work, but for speed and reliability I need USB.

Comment: Ok.  Does your Mac have USB 2 or thunderbolt?

Comment: It's an iMac 2020, and I've tried both cables (Thunderbolt 3 and USB 3)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure on my answer, but I'd go try the following route: open up the network options and

- either create a Wi-Fi hotspot from you iMac and connect to it from your iPhone
- or click the Plus (+) icon and setup a VLAN with the interfaces you'd like Ethernet to travel thru.

Check back with me if you need further instructions I'll write a script or come up with something.

Answer (score -2):

The iPhone will not allow connections to the iPhone over USB. The iPhone can provide hotspot connection over USB to the Mac, but not the other way around. The only way to solve this is jailbreak the iPhone.

However, you can purchase a Ethernet to Lighting adapter and simply plug the ethernet cable directly into the iPhone...this is supported. (I don't make the rules, I just read them out)