# Erase iPhone 7 without service

Tags: iphone, wifi

The wifi on my child's iPhone 7 stopped working, so we got an iPhone SE to replace it. Now we want to erase the old phone, but we cannot turn off "Find My" because there is no apparent way to connect to an Apple server: no phone service because that's been transferred to the new phone, no wifi because wifi is broken on this phone. I can connect it directly to a Mac desktop, but the "Restore" option refuses to work without first disabling "Find My". We can try to disable "Find My" by going directly to iCloud.com/find, but of course the old phone doesn't know about this because it can't connect to anything.

So what do we do?

Maybe temporarily restore phone service to the old phone? How do we do that? Any other options?

Comment: What is the version of iOS running on iPhone 7?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb

Comment: @NimeshNeema: 15.3.

Comment: @lhf: good idea, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to solve this would be to temporarily remove the SIM-card from the new phone and insert it into the old phone for as long as it takes to disable "Find My".

If this is not possible, for example due to using an eSIM, you can also use a Mac to share the computer's internet connection with the phone over USB. Connect the phone with the Mac using a standard USB to Lightning cable, and then on the Mac, use **System Prefences > Sharing** to enable **Internet Sharing**. In the "To computers using" list ensure that there is a checkmark for "iPhone USB".

Comment: I used the second suggestion, also provided by @lhf, and it worked great.