# Can I share my Linux PC's internet to an iPad over USB?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, unix, tethering

I have a similar question to one asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb)

I have an iPad with iOS 15.6 and want to share my Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) Desktop PC's internet with it over an USB cable. First of all, Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: That might best be asked at: https://superuser.com/ as that involves configuring the Linux PC to share its internet connection over USB

Comment: @SteveChambers I will reopen this since superuser community didn't like the question :)